# Expectation of increasing transformation of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Suppose that $X$ is a positive continuous random variable with infinitely differentiable pdf $f_\theta (x)$ and suppose that its expectation is increasing in $\theta$. That is, the function
$$
g_{1}(\theta) = \mathbb{E} [X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} x \, f_\theta(x) \, \mathrm{d} x  
$$
is increasing in $\theta$.

Now suppose that $h$ is infinitely differentiable, positive, and increasing ($h$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, either). Is it true that the function
$$
g_2 (\theta) = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} h(x) \, f_\theta(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
$$
is increasing in $\theta$? (or are there any extra restrictions, such as convexity or concavity, which might ensure that the statement is correct?).

I've tried some examples, like $X \sim $ Normal$(\mu,1)$ along with some increasing transformations, and it seems to work. I've started taking derivatives inside the integral, but I haven't succeeded in proving it. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to impose some conditions on higher moments of $X$ (which presumably also depend on $\theta$). Try a Taylor expansion of $h$ and you'll see them pop out.

Comment: @gogurt In the case $h(x)=x^2$ this leads to the familiar formula $\mathbb E[X^2]=\mathbb E[X]^2+Var(X)$. Is there any reason why the derivative of $E[X]^2+Var(X)$ should turn out to be positive in general?